# How to open and write data into file from API call using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, google-cloud-functions

I wrote an API and the response from that API is array of data. Whenever the response coming from that API i want to store that response in file that is.txt format. I tried but it shows an error like "No such directory or NO such path". How to create file and write data into file from API using node.js. This is the code i wrote :

```
    exports.Entry = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
      var fs = require('fs');
      var a = ['6', '7', '8'];
      var b = ['22', '27', '20'];
      var eachrecord = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        eachrecord += a + b;
      }

      console.log("eachrecord is", eachrecord);

      //Writing each record value into file
     fileWriteSync('./filewriting1.txt');
     function fileWriteSync(filePath){
  var fd = fs.openSync(filePath,'w');
  var length = eachrecord.length;
  for(i = 0;i<length;i++){
    var eachrecordwrite = fs.writeSync(fd,eachrecord[i] + '\n',null,null);

    console.log("hii",eachrecord[i]);

  }
  fs.closeSync(fd);
}
    });
```

How to write data into file from API using node.js

Answer (score 0):

You can only write files to `os.tmpdir()`, which is `/tmp` on Cloud Functions. `/tmp` is a memory based filesystem.  Everything else is read-only.  If you don't intend to do anything with that written file, it will consume memory indefinitely.  You should always delete files written to `/tmp` before the function terminates.  Writing a file to memory like this is almost certainly not the best solution to a problem, unless there is a consumer for that content that can only read it off the local filesystem.

Since you haven't really said what problem you're trying to solve, it's not possible to say what you could be doing instead (that's something for a different question).  But anyway, you can only write to `/tmp`.

Comment: Whenever i got the response from the API , i want to write that response into file and upload that file using SFTP to the some company. I am getting an error in firebase cloud function logs like "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'filewriting1.txt' at Error (native)"

Comment: Yes, I understand your error, and you should be writing to the only writable folder available, as I said in my answer.  But you could consider also writing the content directly to whatever you use to sftp.

Comment: So the tmp file will create in my system or in cloud functions?

Comment: When you deploy the function, it runs entirely in the cloud.  It has no relation to your computers at all.

Comment: Where do i can see the /tmp file in cloud functions?

Comment: There's no way to "see" the file other than through the code your write to access it.  There could be 1000 server instances with their own /tmp in play.

Comment: is there another way write and store file from api